# WSS4J For Android

Tags: android

We have a requirement to write a client on Android w.r.t. Web-Services-Security.

I looked at WSS4J code, not meant for Android.

I don't have a remote idea of how to communicate with a web-service that implements WSS ?

Or any conceptual knowledge, read the wiki for WSS , though not much helpful-or i am too dumb to understand.

Any ideas , suggestions would help.

Thanks.

Comment: C'mon..how is that helping...some knowledge here and there is what we have...we have done simple web-service communication , SSL implementation for Android , but for WSS we aren't able to find any code-samples , that-is-why we are here to ask the guys/experts who have already worked on it , maybe they can provide inputs on steps to be taken forward. Thanks.

Comment: You meant platform ?....For Android

Comment: No, platform is pretty obvious from the question title and the tags and your mention of Android several times. I mean what are you trying to connect to using WSS?

Comment: A remote server providing web-services over https...Pardon me if things don't seem right. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone ?. Is WSS4J not the right choice w.r.t. Android ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [kSoap](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/) making your way to security, or [Apache Santuario repackaged](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1302/) cause javax.xml.soap with javax.xml.crypto are not in Android.

It is not easy but when you don't know how, that is the moment you learn ;)

Hope it helps

EDIT: I updated the answer cause crypto itself is not Android, see link n.2